# DNS on Synology Diskstation with Comcast

Tags: networking, router, dns, synology

I was fortunate to find out that our Diskstation DS1511+ as the ability to host web sites and I am trying to get it setup as a development environment.

So far I am able to have a domain forward to our office WAN IP which is on Comcast. But I've found out that we cannot access the domain internally. After doing some research online, it appears that the way that Comcast has it's network configured I'd have to go about running an internal DNS for the domain to resolve correctly within our office.

I've been following the directions that I've found here:
http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=130&t=67565

But to no avail, I cannot seem to get it to work correctly and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

- I have resolution services enabled and have enable forwarders checked and set to the primary and secondary WAN DNS IP's from Comcast.
- I currently have the DNS in the Diskstation set to the domain that I want (beta.domain.com) to the IP of the Diskstation: 192.168.0.103 which created the A record and the ns.beta.domain.com set to the Diskstation IP:

[image]

- I did login to my Comcast modem and set the primary LAN DNS IP to the Diskstation (192.168.0.103) and a secondary IP address to a Comcast WAN DNS IP:

[image]

When I try to release and renew my network interface it still pulls from my router IP address (192.168.0.1) as the DNS (I'm on a Mac) so unlike the instructions from the link above, it's not pulling the Diskstation IP as the DNS:

[image]

I've released the DNS info from the router since that is the one that is doing DHCP and it appears to be pulling in the right info from the modem:

[image]

Overall I just want to know if I am heading down the correct path or not? I know that I will have to setup rDNS pointers, but I just want to see if I am getting a grasp on this correctly. I feel that I am missing something somewhere.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!